# Drag and Drop to an IE HTML page from an external Windows Application - how to make to copy, not move

Tags: javascript, html, internet-explorer, drag-and-drop

I decided to add drag & drop functionality to text inputs. It works nicely apart from the dragged text disappears from a source application, for instance, from Notepad. How to prevent such a move and to leave the text in a source application?

My code is very simple:

```
<input id="_MagicInput" title="" ondragover = "highlightDropArea(event);" ondragleave = "dragLeave(event);"  ondrop = "drop2Gx(event); return false;" onpaste = "handlerPaste(); return false;" type="number" />
```

```
function highlightDropArea(event) {
  event.target.style.background = "yellow";
  event.target.style.border = "3px dotted red";
}

function dragLeave(event) {
  event.target.style.background = "gold";
  event.target.style.border = "";
}

function drop2Gx(evt) {
  evt.stopPropagation();
  evt.preventDefault();
  handlerPaste(evt.dataTransfer.getData("Text"));
  dragLeave(evt);
}
```

I don't need a cross-browser solution, because it's an HTA.

Comment: What is `handlerPaste`?

Comment: handlerPaste is just my function that processes pasting data.

Comment: Given the simplicity of the rest of your code, handlerPaste is likely to  be where the issue is.

Comment: @Yuri, I suggest you to post your whole sample code to produce the issue. It can help to find and narrow down the issue.

Comment: Let me simplify the task The code below will copy a drag&dropped text into Chrome but move it into IE. Just select some text in notepad and drop it into the input field.  I don't want a user to loose his text, so it has to be a copy, not move. I need a solution for IE 11.
 <!DOCTYPE HTML> 
<html>
 <head> 
</head>
 <body>
 <input />
 </body> 
</html>

Comment: The problem is that I cannot find where to add
 event.dataTransfer.dropEffect = "copy";  
nor interrupt returning confirmation to Drag&Drop sourse application.

Comment: Not sure, how your code is working on your side. I made a test with above sample code but it is not working my side and no any event get executed while drag and drop.